# Working principle of Ranque–Hilsch Vortex Tube

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, experimental-physics, refrigeration

I am not able to understand the reason for temperature separation and flow reversal in a counter-flow vortex tube refrigeration system.

[image]

As per some sources, "Compressed air is passed through the nozzle .Then air expands and acquires high velocity due to particular shape of the nozzle. A vortex flow is created in the chamber and air travels in spiral like motion along the periphery of the hot side. This flow is restricted by the valve. When the pressure of the air near valve is made more than outside by partly closing the valve, a reversed axial flow through the core of the hot side starts from high-pressure region to low-pressure region. During this process, heat transfer takes place between reversed stream and forward stream. Therefore, air stream through the core gets cooled below the inlet temperature of the air in the vortex tube, while air stream in forward direction gets heated up. The cold stream is escaped through the back side cold part, while hot stream is passed through the opening of the valve."

But if energy is being transferred from reversed stream (colder one) to the forward stream (hotter one) then doesn't it violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics?

Comment: What happens with free expansion? An aerosol can…

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Then worth some research.

Comment: this question has an answer on the physics stack exchange. go there are search on "vortex tube".

Comment: @nielsnielsen but they are wrong answers - including the one that references this faulty paper - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275024199_The_Maximum_COP_of_Vortex_Tubes.

Comment: "During this process, heat transfer takes place between reversed stream and forward stream." No it doesn't. Or if it does, it is in the only possible direction - warm to cold.

Comment: @phil sweet, do you have a correct reference? I have been intrigued about these things for years.

Comment: No, everybody does things a little different. What you want is the COP. if you start from the same room - compress isothermally to perimeter pressure - add momentum to perimeter speed - admit to machine with rotating walls and some vanes - this displaces perimeter inwards - recapture momentum with the vanes - expand adiabatically to lower temperature at the same time. There isn't a closed solution for the best COP solution. Figuring out the relationship between pressure, density, and temp as a function of radius within the machine isn't easy either. It converges decently though.

Comment: The momentum recapture improves COP, but does it lower or raise the final temp? If I just want to shrink a bushing for a press fit using shop air, I don't really care about COP, just temp.

Comment: Dumping the high temp air through a valve is in lieu of recovering the momentum using vanes. It's really just a turbo expander in disguise.